# How do modern tracking scripts submit events and user attributes to a server?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, analytics, segment

How do [modern tracking scripts](http://grow.segment.com/data-tracking-essentials.pdf) that track events and users and are loaded through a CDN submit this data to a server? There are some [scripts online](https://github.com/segmentio/analytics.js/blob/master/analytics.js) but it's hard to get the bigger picture from thousands of lines of Javascript.

The options I have come across so far are `<img />` with params or a `<script />` with params. Is there a way to do Ajax requests without cross-domain security issues?